# Is my f' string disabling my sorted() function?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to sort and enumerate(after this issue is resolved) parsed data from craigslist using sorted() to sort my values by the newest posting in elapsed minutes. I've got a feeling that it's my f' string causing the issue, but I'm not sure.

Expected Output:

[5712]:  Mar 26:   Master Licensed Electricians

[9987]:  Mar 23:   Microsoft O365/Exchange Consultant:

[27101]:  Mar 11:   Technicians needed immediately!:

[41942]:  Mar  1:   IT Support Technician:

[41945]:  Mar  1:   Network Hardware and Support Engineer:

Resulting Output:

[5712]:  Mar 26:   Master Licensed Electricians

[41942]:  Mar  1:   IT Support Technician:

[41945]:  Mar  1:   Network Hardware and Support Engineer:

[9987]:  Mar 23:   Microsoft O365/Exchange Consultant:

[27101]:  Mar 11:   Technicians needed immediately!:

Code block:

```
def outputEntries(posts):
for post in (posts):
    titleDiv = post.find('a', class_='result-title')
    postTitle = titleDiv.get_text()
    postURL = titleDiv.get('href')
    postDate = post.find('time', title_=[]).get_text()
    postTimeText = post.find('time').get('datetime')
    postTime = datetime.strptime(postTimeText, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
    elapsedMinutes = (datetime.now() - postTime).total_seconds() / 60
    rounded_EM = [math.ceil(elapsedMinutes)]
    #sorted_EM = sorted(rounded_EM, key=lambda x:x[1])
    #sorted(rounded_EM, key=int)

    print(f'{sorted(rounded_EM, key=int)}:  {postDate}:   {postTitle}:     {postURL}')
```

Comments are saved methods of sorting/enumerating for troubleshooting.

Comment: `rounded_EM` only ever contains a single number at a time. What do you expect sorting it to accomplish?

Comment: The f-string has nothing to do with sorting anything. Why would that affect the order in which your results are printed? You need to create an array containing all the results you want to print first, then sort them, then print them all.

Comment: Honestly not exactly sure, in that this is my first project in coding ever. I was looking to store the output from 'elapsedMinutes' into 'rounded_EM' as a list while using 'math.ceil' to rid myself of a float value problem I was having. Then using that rounded list in 'rounded_EM' (more-so as a variable), to sort in an ascending order to provide the most recent posting.

Comment: It was the only thing I thought could be affecting it, outside of something I don't understand, because I hadn't messed with the f' string. I didn't think it would, but this is my first project ever, so I'm not very familiar with rules/stipulations. Thanks for pointing me to using an array!